# continuity of $f(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}\left(x+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$ verification

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-convergence

I wish to check for which $x$'s the function:

$$f(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}\left(x+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$$

is continuous.

I'm not sure I solved it the right way, please let me know if I made mistakes.

Here is what I did:

I first check for uniform convergence:

for $x\le-1$ or $x\ge 1$ we get that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)\ne 0$ so it is not an option.

for $-1\lt x \lt 1$ I used the root test:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\sqrt[n]{\left(x+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n}\right|=|x|$$

so for $-1\lt x \lt 1$ the series uniformly converges, and since each $f_n$ is continuous, $f$ is continuous there.

Any corrections will be very helpful.

Comment: I'd consider binomial expansion and then rearrangement to convert to a power series. This new power series will then agree with the original series within its region of convergence. Thus you have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} n^{-2(n-k)} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left ( \sum_{n=k}^\infty {n \choose k} n^{-2(n-k)} \right ) x^k$ within the region of convergence of this power series. (I think I actually have a slight error here: $n$ should never be $0$.) Moreover you get uniform convergence on compact subsets of the disk of convergence.

Comment: It seems generally sensible to me. One caveat is that you might want to be explicit why the limit of individual terms is non-zero in the $x=-1$ case, because the modulus is less than one there.

Comment: (Also, you write $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x)\neq0$ whereas I think you want to say something like $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\neq 0$ ($f_n(x)$ being $(x+\frac1{n^2})^n$); $f(x) is not defined in those cases because the _individual_ terms don't have a limit.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thank you

Comment: @Ian thank you. I have yet learned power series but when I do i will do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The series does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1).$ You can see this by noting $\sup_{(-1,1)} |f_n| \ge 1$ for each $n.$ However you may be able to show the series converges uniformly on $[-a,a]$ for each $a, 0<a<1.$ That would prove $f$ is continuous on each $[-a,a],$ and that will be enough to give the conclusion you claimed.

Comment: Why did this not receive an up vote ... until now?  (+1)